# Support library for BLE for devices lower than api level 18

Tags: android

I am new to BLE concept on android .

Is there any support library to use BLE on android devices with Api lower than 18

Answer (score 1):

No, BLE was not supported by hardware until devices after API 18. There may be some exceptions for specific device manufacturers, but not that I'm aware of.